# Text search doesn't return anything for certain words

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a database with an "entries" collection that is structured like so:

```
{
    tags: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Tag"
        }
    ],
    body: String
}
```

I wanted a search feature on my site, so I created a text index on the "body" property like this:

```
db.entries.createIndex( { body: "text" } )
```

It worked fine. I created a couple of entries and ran `db.entries.find()`. I got this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c2e3d9fd1d5dd121ed85695"), "tags" : [ ], "body" : "some text", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c2e3dadd1d5dd121ed85696"), "tags" : [ ], "body" : "text some", "__v" : 0 }
```

So far, so good. I search `db.entries.find({$text: { $search: "text" }})` and both of the entries are returned. But when I search `db.entries.find({$text: { $search: "some" }})` I get nothing.

I tried this again with different words. "church" works fine, but "more" doesn't return anything either. Why???

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use text (string) instead of something like regex?
Something like `db.entries.find({body: /text/ig })` ?

Comment: I'm not very experienced, so I know almost nothing about regular expressions. I did a little research though. I know "i" is unnecessary because MongoDB text searches are case-insensitive by default, and I think using "g" would just increase server response time with no added benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB text index drops some language-specific words that are considered as [Stopwords](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#supported-languages-and-stop-words) and `some` is one of them. To fix that you can build your index with `default_language: "none"` - this prevents any stopwords and whole content is getting indexed:

```
db.entries.createIndex(
    { body : "text" },
    { default_language: "none" }
)
```

Full list of English stopwords [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt).

Comment: That worked, thank you! I think this answer is out there, I just didn't know what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

you can run the following in a mongo shell to allow text search over the 
db.entries.createIndex( { body: "text" } );
Next 
db.entries.find( { $text: { $search: "some text" } } );
OR-OR
db.entries.find( { body: { $in: "some text" } }  )
I am trying my best level answer,i think it is useful...if not working don't bother