# $text based search using mongojs doesn't appear to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongojs

I have a mongo collection where I need to combine q regex search with a $text search as well. Using Robo 3t this seems to work fine and I get want I want.

However when trying to get this running in my node app along with mongojs, the query wont work until I remove the $text.

```
var inRiverCode = req.body.RiverCode
var inSpecies = req.body.Species
var inMonth = req.body.Month

db.rodAvail.find({
    //RiverCode: inRiverCode, $text: { $search: "as"}, WeekStartDisplay:  
{$regex: inMonth}
    $and : [  {$text: { $search: inSpecies }},
    {RiverCode: inRiverCode, WeekStartDisplay: {$regex: inMonth}}]

}, function(err, rodAvailList) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
});
```

Am I doing something silly like a mistype in my query or is $text search not supported in mongojs.

I did ask on the git page but its very quite so I expected  a long wait for a reply.

https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs/issues/369

Comment: I'm not sure but stopwords might be the reason why you can't get your document, you can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54026712/text-search-doesnt-return-anything-for-certain-words/54026841#54026841

Comment: Thank you very much indeed sir, that did the trick and I had no idea that would of been it